# Create chainned menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.5 as CMS to develop my personal website.

The reason I'm writting, is that I need a way to implement a code or plugin to allow users to navigate through posts using dependent(chained) dropdown lists.

In other words I would like 3 dropdown menus to be dynamically populated based on the selection chosen in the previous dropdown lists.

This would consist of:

Dropdown 1: Category * 
Dropdown 2: Sub- Category * 
Dropdown 3: List of posts in Sub-Category *

*Dropdown 1 would be pre populated with categories. 
*Dropdown 2 would list the sub categories of menu 1 based on the user selection. 
*Dropdown 3 would list the posts in the sub category chosen in menu 2.

To help you understand further, in my website I have the Category "TV Series" which has as sub-categories(child) other series, like "Dexter", "CSI:Miami" etc. Series also have other sub-categories(child) the number of seasons, like "Season 1" "Season 2" "Season N". Each season contains the appropriate posts.

The Hierarchy is like this:

Tv Series (main category) 
-Dexter
--Season 1
--Season 2
--Season n

-CSI:Miami 
--Season 1
--Season 2
--Season n

So for example the dynamic dropdowns I would like to use are the following:

Dropdown 1: Select TV Show (Category)
Dropdown 2: Select Season (sub-category)
Dropdown 3: Select Episode (posts)

I would really appreciate if you could help me with the matter as I was searching the web for the past few days without any results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Multi-Level-Navigation Plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/